# React js -[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, passive-event-listeners

I am working on React js on one code where I am using select element and onChange event.

```
  handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>         
               <label>
                List
                    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <option value="one">One</option>
                        <option value="two">Two</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
        )
```

But I am getting this warning again and again in chrome.
"[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.". Is there any resolution for it.

Comment: You sure it's this component that is causing the problem? I'm quite sure you have an external or outside script listening on the mousewheel event (This component doesn't even touch the mousewheel.)

Comment: Yes whenever I click on select,i get this warning

Comment: Just render a simple `<select>` with no handlers. This has to be an outside script.

Comment: Removed handleChange,still same warning

Comment: Start checking for other scripts that are on the page. You have an external event that is listening on mousewheel, that just happens to trigger when you're selecting a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all `scroll` and `touch` events expect to be "passive" if `preventDefault()` is not called. But it's not that easy..

1. Not all browsers support passive event listener option.
2. If it's the 3rd party code that is causing the warning, modifying it's source code is a bad bad practice.
3. Packages like `default-passive-events` jsut blindly apply passive attribute ignoring the usage of `preventDefault()` and that might cause your script break..
4. Applying `passive: false` to all the events will remove the warning, but will not improve the performance. Whats the point then?

I was dealing with such issue not a long ago and created a package that overwrites `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener` and add `passive` option to all the events that do not `preventDefault` and if browsers supports it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passive-events-support

This not only removed the warning, but also improved the performance.
Make sure to pass only necessary events instead of default. In this case just 'mousewheel':

```
import { passiveSupport } from 'passive-events-support/src/utils'

passiveSupport(['mousewheel'])
```

If you want a modular way, you can find an example in the docs.
Make sure to import this script before any other script that causes that warning.